# setState in React results in Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: reactjs

I have an very simple piece of React code as im trying to understand the concepts.

In the code below if I comment out the setState function I can see that selectNumber runs when I expect it too. However when I try and change the state's numbersBurnt value I get an error.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
    state = {
        numbersBurnt: [1]
    };
    selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {    
      console.log('This was run');
      this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        numbersBurnt = [1];
      });
    };
      render() {
      return /* Something */;
    }
  }
```

Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: numbersBurnt is not defined`

UPDATE: Here is the full code:

```
function Stars(props) {
    const starsRandNo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
  let stars = [];
  for (let i=0; i < starsRandNo; i++) {
    stars.push(<span key={i} className="star">{i+1}</span>)
  }
  return <div>{stars}</div>;
}

function StarsBtn(props) {
    const starsBtnClick = () => {
    alert('was clicked');
  }
    return <button onClick={starsBtnClick}>Change no of stars</button>
}

function NumberOptions(props) {
    const no = 9;
  let numbers = [];  
  const burnTest = (i) => {
    if (props.numbersBurnt.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
      return "number-options number-options--burnt";
    } else {
      return "number-options";
    }
  }
  for (let i=0; i < no; i++) {  
    numbers.push(<span className={burnTest(i)}
    onClick={() => props.selectNumber(i+1)} >{i+1}</span>)
  }
  return <div>{ numbers }</div>;
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    state = {
    numbersBurnt: [1]
  };
  selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {    
    console.log(this.state.numbersBurnt);

    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      numbersBurnt: [2]
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.numbersBurnt)});

    console.log(this.state.numbersBurnt);

  };
  render() {
    return <div>
                    <Stars />
            <br />
            <StarsBtn />
            <br />
            <br />
                <NumberOptions numbersBurnt={this.state.numbersBurnt} 
            selectNumber={this.selectNumber} />
            </div>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  mountNode
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setState , you should be using a `:` and not a `=`. Also remove the `;` and the `prevState and props` in your setState as you are not making use of them

```
class Game extends React.Component {
    state = {
        numbersBurnt: [1]
    };
    selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {    
      console.log('This was run');
      this.setState({
        numbersBurnt: [1]
      }, () => { console.log(this.state.numbersBurnt)});
    };
      render() {
      return /* Something */;
    }
  }
```

```js
function Stars(props) {
    const starsRandNo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
  let stars = [];
  for (let i=0; i < starsRandNo; i++) {
    stars.push(<span key={i} className="star">{i+1}</span>)
  }
  return <div>{stars}</div>;
}

function StarsBtn(props) {
    const starsBtnClick = () => {
    alert('was clicked');
  }
    return <button onClick={starsBtnClick}>Change no of stars</button>
}

function NumberOptions(props) {
    const no = 9;
  let numbers = [];  
  const burnTest = (i) => {
    if (props.numbersBurnt.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
      return "number-options number-options--burnt";
    } else {
      return "number-options";
    }
  }
  for (let i=0; i < no; i++) {  
    numbers.push(<span className={burnTest(i)}
    onClick={() => props.selectNumber(i+1)} >{i+1}</span>)
  }
  return <div>{ numbers }</div>;
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    state = {
    numbersBurnt: [1]
  };
  selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {    
   

    this.setState({
      numbersBurnt: [2]
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.numbersBurnt)});

    

  };
  render() {
    return <div>
                    <Stars />
            <br />
            <StarsBtn />
            <br />
            <br />
                <NumberOptions numbersBurnt={this.state.numbersBurnt} 
            selectNumber={this.selectNumber} />
            </div>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Im no longer getting the error but when I log out this.state.numbersBurnt I can see that its value hasnt changed.

Comment: Log its value in the callback function, as mentioned in the updated answer

Comment: Its still not updating the value for me. Ive updated my answer will my full code (running in https://jscomplete.com/repl).

Comment: You don't need the prevState and props in your setState, since you are not using them, without that its working

Answer (score 1):

You try it.

React state is specify in the constructor function.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbersBurnt: [1]
    }
  }
  selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {    
    console.log('This was run');
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      numbersBurnt: [1]
    });
  };
 render() {
  return /* Something */;
 }
}
```

more simple.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbersBurnt: [1]
    }
  }
  selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {    
    console.log('This was run');
    this.setState({
      numbersBurnt: [1]
    });
  };
 render() {
  return /* Something */;
 }
}
```

You can omit `prevState, props`.

Comment: Its not necessary to specify the state in the constructor, it works without that too

Comment: The de facto standard is to specify the state in the constructor

Comment: Even I was arguing on that for once, but it turned out that its not necessary, maybe if I find the docs that convinced me, I can share that with you

Comment: I think there is any reason why you say so far.
Since this tends to be a story of an engineer hobby, let's not talk about it here.